# Is it possible to remove Emergency call feature on the lock screen?

Tags: iphone, screen-lock

Is it possible to remove this feature? It's really annoying when you miss-click on it. Since my iPhone lags a lot this happens too often.

- iOS version: 4.2.1
- iPhone: 3G

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this in native iOS (without a jailbreak).

The emergency call option is available with both the simple and complex passcode.

I assume the goal is that it would allow anyone to make an emergency call even if they don't know or forgot the passcode, and as a result could be an important safety feature.

The only way to disable it is to turn off the passcode - something with obvious undesirable effects.

Comment: I don't want anyone to be able to use my iPhone, since it's my phone. if you are able to make emergency phone calls, people could do it as a prank.

Comment: @Alvar, Yes. Agreed. However, I'm guessing it also goes with the fact that all cell phones are supposed to be able to perform an emergency call - regardless of the current standing with the carrier. While I see what you are saying about playing a prank, I probably have other issues if someone has my iPhone that would play a prank like that. And, second, I know if I need to make an emergency call, chances are I want access to that very quickly. Just my 2¢.

Comment: Ayyyyeeee does this option still not exist? My toddler called 9-1-1 while I was sleeping because of the emergency option. I’d rather just have SOS working and not the emergency call on my lock screen. 

Comment: @Daisy, unfortunately, I'm not aware of any of updates to this part of iOS

Comment: One suggestion I saw on Apple forum was to display an additional screen with a small random number to enter correctly first, think like a simple captcha with say "Enter 4 2 0 2 to continue" , point being that would likely prevent the little ones who play with the phone being able to get to the emergency call screen ( as those old enough to understand that would hopefully be able to realise not to call emergency ) but simple enough for those who need it to be able to do it in an emergency. Three or four numerical is likely sufficient.